# Counting all pairs that differ by k

Tags: optimization, performance, ruby

Given an array of numbers and another number *k*, how can I find the number of 2 elements such as their difference is equal to *k*?

```
def pairs(n,k)
  n.combination(2).select{|x|(x[0]-x[1] == k) || (x[1]-x[0] == k)}.count
end
```

I ran a test where n was an array of 8000 different 10 digit numbers.

However, this took about 30 seconds to solve, and ideally it would solve in under a second.

It looks like there is a problem with my algorithm, but I can't figure out how to make it more efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to do it.

**Code**

```
def count_pairs(arr, k)
  arr.flat_map { |i| [[i,:num],[i+k,:npk]] }
     .group_by { |i,_| i }
     .reduce(0) do |tot,(_k,a)|
        nbr_num = a.count { |_,type| type == :num }
        tot + [nbr_num, a.size-nbr_num].min
      end
end
```

**Example**

```
k = 3
arr = [ 6, 3,  3,  3, 14, 11, 14, 11, 15, 11, 14,
       17, 7, 18, 13,  2,  4, 14,  0, 18,  6,  4]

count_pairs(arr, 3)
  #=> 9
```

**Explanation**

The problem is to determine the number of pairs whose difference equals `k`. That is equivalent to asking for the number of elements that can be matched with a value that is larger in value by `k`, such that no element is matched by more than one element that is smaller by `k`.

The first step in answering that question is to replace each element `i` in the array with two elements, `[i, :num]` and `[i+k, :npk]`, where `:num` indicates it's the original number and `:npk` indicates it's the original number plus `k`.

We then group all elements on the first value in each 2-tuple. For `arr` above, this grouping for the number `7` is as follows:

```
7=>[[7,  :npk], [7, :npk],  [7, :num]],
```

We see that two of the `7's` are `npk`'s (`4+3`), and one is the original number `7`. The number of pairings is the lesser of the number of `num`'s and the number of `npk`s. Here that is one.

I will now go through the steps to determine the number of pairing in `arr` above for `k=3`.

To make it easier to follow, I will first sort `arr` (though the method neither requires `arr` to be sorted nor sorts it):

```
arr = [ 0,  2,  3,  3,  3,  4,  4,  6,  6,  7, 11,
       11, 11, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 17, 18, 18]

a = arr.flat_map { |i| [[i,:num],[i+k,:npk]] } 
  #=> [[0,  :num], [3,  :npk], [2,  :num], [5,  :npk], [3,  :num],
  #    [6,  :npk], [3,  :num], [6,  :npk], [3,  :num], [6,  :npk],
  #    [4,  :num], [7,  :npk], [4,  :num], [7,  :npk], [6,  :num],
  #    [9,  :npk], [6,  :num], [9,  :npk], [7,  :num], [10, :npk],
  #    [11, :num], [14, :npk], [11, :num], [14, :npk], [11, :num],
  #    [14, :npk], [13, :num], [16, :npk], [14, :num], [17, :npk],
  #    [14, :num], [17, :npk], [14, :num], [17, :npk], [14, :num],
  #    [17, :npk], [15, :num], [18, :npk], [17, :num], [20, :npk],
  #    [18, :num], [21, :npk], [18, :num], [21, :npk]]

b = a.group_by { |i,_| i }
  #=> { 0=>[[0,  :num]],
  #     3=>[[3,  :npk], [3, :num],  [3, :num],  [3, :num]],
  #     2=>[[2,  :num]],
  #     5=>[[5,  :npk]],
  #     6=>[[6,  :npk], [6, :npk],  [6, :npk],  [6, :num], [6, :num]],
  #     4=>[[4,  :num], [4, :num]],
  #     7=>[[7,  :npk], [7, :npk],  [7, :num]],
  #     9=>[[9,  :npk], [9, :npk]],
  #    10=>[[10, :npk]],
  #    11=>[[11, :num], [11, :num], [11, :num]],
  #    14=>[[14, :npk], [14, :npk], [14, :npk], [14, :num],
  #         [14, :num], [14, :num], [14, :num]],
  #    13=>[[13, :num]],
  #    16=>[[16, :npk]],
  #    17=>[[17, :npk], [17, :npk], [17, :npk], [17, :npk], [17, :num]],
  #    15=>[[15, :num]],
  #    18=>[[18, :npk], [18, :num], [18, :num]],
  #    20=>[[20, :npk]],
  #    21=>[[21, :npk], [21, :npk]]}

b.reduce(0) do |tot,(_k,a)|
   nbr_num = a.count { |_,type| type == :num }
   tot + [nbr_num, a.size-nbr_num].min
 end
  #=> 9
```

To clarify how the final step was performed, I will first convert each element of `b` to a 4-tuple:

```
[ value, num count, npk count, [num count, npk count].min }

c = b.map do |k,a|
      nbr_num = a.count { |_,type| type == :num }
      nbr_npk = a.size - nbr_num
      [k, nbr_num, nbr_npk, [nbr_num, nbr_npk].min]
    end
  #=> [[ 0, 1, 0, 0], [ 3, 3, 1, 1], [ 2, 1, 0, 0], [ 5, 0, 1, 0],
  #    [ 6, 2, 3, 2], [ 4, 2, 0, 0], [ 7, 1, 2, 1], [ 9, 0, 2, 0],
  #    [10, 0, 1, 0], [11, 3, 0, 0], [14, 4, 3, 3], [13, 1, 0, 0],
  #    [16, 0, 1, 0], [17, 1, 4, 1], [15, 1, 0, 0], [18, 2, 1, 1],
  #    [20, 0, 1, 0], [21, 0, 2, 0]]

c.reduce(0) { |tot, (*_,cnt)| tot + cnt }
  #=> 9
```

Answer (score 8):

The logical solution here is to sort the data in order, then scan it looking ahead for the partner that has the right difference to the target. Slicing, and combinations, etc. are not going to be the most efficient algorithm.

A sort with \$O(n \log n)\$ scaling, and a simple 'look ahead' to find a potential pairing, will be much, much faster.

If your data has duplicates, then you will need to look for multiple matches for the correct difference.

Consider doing a binary search for the target value, which will still leave you at an overall performance of \$O(n \log n)\$ algorithm

Comment: Please explain in greater detail how you would handle duplicates--the most interesting aspect of the problem--or, preferably, provide code.

Comment: @CarySwoveland - the simple approach would be best here... the b-search will find any of the matches, and then you need to loop forward from the match, and also backwards. For each match, you need to increment the count. You need to take in to account the special case where k==0 in that case too.

Answer (score 2):

Because you call `combination(2)` you are actually getting a much larger array than what you start out with.  Don't you mean to partition the array collection by pairs, rather than taking all elements of the array and getting every combination of possible pairs?  Instead of dealing with 4k pairs, you are dealing with almost 32 million pais.

Your method name suggests that you will return pairs from a given array, but it returns an integer.  The name doesn't convey the idea of the methods return.  This makes it more difficult to understand the intent of your method, even with the code.

```
def pairs_with_difference(array, difference)
  array.each_slice(2).select {|a, b| (a - b).abs == difference }.size
end
```

This will only use 4000 arrays, converting the array into an array of arrays containing 2 elements each, given the 8000 element array you mentioned.

<strike>I have not timed it though.</strike>

```
Rehearsal -----------------------------------------
pairs  29.900000   0.210000  30.110000 ( 30.665199)
mine    0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.003723)
------------------------------- total: 30.110000sec

            user     system      total        real
pairs  27.170000   0.040000  27.210000 ( 27.788127)
mine    0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.003164)
```

Comment: your solution assumes that the solution pairs are neighbours, and also that they are in even-pairs. Consider `[1,3,4,6]` looking for difference `1`. The solution would be `3,4` but `each_slice` will return only `1,3` and `4,6` as candidates.

Comment: This is true, given the question I am trying to assume the simplest case.  Given no small sample to observe, and no correct results given, it is the solution I came up with.  Hence my question (in my answer) to help clarify his intent with the use of combination.